# Eigenvectors of Pauli vectors

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

For a Pauli vector defined by $\vec{\sigma}=\sigma_1 \hat{x_1}+\sigma_2 \hat{x_2}+\sigma_3 \hat{x_3}$, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) states that $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$ has two eigenvector given by

$$
\psi_+ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2|\vec{a}|(a_3+|\vec{a}|)}} \begin{bmatrix} a_3 + |\vec{a}| \\ a_1 + ia_2 \end{bmatrix}; \qquad
  \psi_- = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2|\vec{a}|(a_3+|\vec{a}|)}} \begin{bmatrix} ia_2 - a_1 \\  a_3 + |\vec{a}| \end{bmatrix} ~ 
$$

However, these formula is invalid in the case when $\vec{a}=(0,0,-a)$ where $a$ is a positive number. I worked out other form of these eigenvectors such as

$$
\psi_+ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2|\vec{a}|(|\vec{a}|-a_3 )}} \begin{bmatrix} ia_2-a_1 \\  a_3-|\vec{a}| \end{bmatrix}; \qquad
  \psi_- = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2|\vec{a}|(|\vec{a}|-a_3 )}} \begin{bmatrix} a_3 - |\vec{a}| \\  a_1+ia_2 \end{bmatrix} ~ 
$$

but these again are invalid in the case when $\vec{a}=(0,0,a)$.

My question is whether there exist a expression for each of these two eigenvectors that is well defined for arbitary vector $\vec{a}\in\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'works' precisely, but a pair that is defined everywhere is $\left| \psi_+\right>=\cos(\theta/2)\left| +\right>+\sin(\theta/2)e^{i\phi}\left| -\right>$ and $\left| \psi_-\right>=-\sin(\theta/2)e^{-i \phi}\left| +\right>+\cos(\theta/2)\left| -\right>$. Here $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the polar and azimuthal angles formed by the vector $\mathbf{a}$ in spherical co-ordinates, and $\left|\pm \right>$ are the eigenvectors of $\sigma_z$

Comment: @Sal Should make that an answer.