# Pauli vectors formalism.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

I'm in search of some informations (or good sources) about the formalism of pauli vectors; in particular i refer to any useful formulae like those shown in ([Eigenvectors of Pauli vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497001/eigenvectors-of-pauli-vectors)). Infact, i was asked to solve an excercise in which i would had to express a matrix in the basis that diagonalize another one, and i couldn't hold up with all that calculations (find eigenvalues, eigenvectors, the inverse of the eigenvectors matrix, ecc)... then, i was said that i should had used notorious facts about eigenvalues/eigenvectors of matrices expressible in terms of pauli matrices.. the problem is that i never knew about those facts, nor suggested book contains similiar informations. Moreover i wasn't able to find anything googling myself.. could anybody provide good sources about?

---

**NOTE)** I would appreciate a complete treatment of the above topics; for example in ([Eigenvectors of Pauli vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497001/eigenvectors-of-pauli-vectors)) there wasn't the general case of: $A=\alpha_0I+\vec{\alpha} \cdot \vec{\sigma}$

Comment: The topics you want to have a look at in mathematical terms are the Lie group $SU(2)$ and the lie algebra $su(2)$ (and irreducible representations of them). In physics terms this is usually called "angular momentum" or "spin". You can look for example in the quantum mechanics book from Sakurai which treats angular momentum and the Pauli matrices in detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i took a look on sakurai as you suggested, but i couldn't find the formula given in (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497001/eigenvectors-of-pauli-vectors). May i have mislooked? Can you provide the page (if you know) where i can find it? Or again, do you know another source where i can find the demonstration of it?

Comment: It is in section 3.2.5 "Rotations in the Two-Component Formalism" on page 162 of the edition i have, starting with equation 3.68 the eigenvector of $\vec{\alpha} \vec{\sigma}$ is constructed, when $\| \vec{\alpha}\| =1$. Note that the case with $A= \alpha_0 I + \vec{\alpha} \vec{\sigma}$ and $\| \alpha \| \neq 1 $ follows trivially from the case there.